# Copy to clipboard JavaScript in webform aspx with to many blank spaces

Tags: javascript, asp.net

my problem is the following, I have a javascript function that is responsible for copying the mail of a span from a webform

aspx

```
         <div id="thisEmail" name="thisEmail" style="display:none; margin-left:40px; font-size: 20px;font-weight: 400;color: #F32D28">
            <label id="copyEmailToClipboard" class="widget-chashier-bitcoin-textcopy" onclick="copytext(this)" style="cursor:pointer;padding-right: 25px;">
                    <span >
                        <span class="icon icon-copy"></span><span id="copyarea" style="text-align:left" class="txt">cs@betonline.ag</span>
                        <p></p>
                    </span>
            </label>
         <br/>
            <small id="copiedToClipboard" class="widget-chashier-bitcoin-textcopy" style="display: none; font-size:12px;   padding-right: 30px;">Copied to clipboard!</small>
        </div>
```

JavaScript

```
      function copytext(elemento) {
  var $temp = $("<input>")
  $("body").append($temp);
      $temp.val($(elemento).text()).select();
              try {
            document.execCommand("copy");

        } catch (ignore) {
        // user should manually copy
        }

        if (elemento.id == 'copyEmailToClipboard') {
            console.log(    $("#copiedToClipboard"))
            $("#copiedToClipboard").fadeIn();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#copiedToClipboard").fadeOut();
            }, 1500);
        }
  $temp.remove();
}
```

when paste in the browser works fine, paste:

> cs@betonline.ag

but you paste in notepad paste:"

> ```
>                                               cs@betonline.ag
> ```

Thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try stripping the white space with something like this

```
str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

In your case:

```
var text = $(elemento).text();
text = text.replace(/\s+/g, '');
$temp.val(text).select();
```

Comment: It does not work, it keeps sticking with many tabs on both sides